# Hudson ArtifactDeployer does not copy jar files

Tags: jar, jenkins, copy, hudson, artifact

I am using hudson to copy some files into different folder locations. destination folder locations are also on the same machine as hudson server.

Build is successful, but the copy fails with the below error. Any one saw this before?

This is the plugin being used in the Jobs - Build section:

```
[ArtifactDeployer] - Deploy artifacts from workspace to remote directories 


[ArtifactDeployer] - Starting deployment from the build step ...

FATAL: com/sun/jna/TypeMapper
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jna/TypeMapper
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:420)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
at org.jruby.ext.posix.POSIXFactory$1.<init>(POSIXFactory.java:13)
at org.jruby.ext.posix.POSIXFactory.<clinit>(POSIXFactory.java:12)
at com.atlassian.ant.tasks.PermissionsUtils.<clinit>(PermissionsUtils.java:17)
at com.atlassian.ant.tasks.CopyWithPerms.doFileOperations(CopyWithPerms.java:75)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.artifactdeployer.service.LocalCopy$1CopyImpl.doFileOperations(LocalCopy.java:38)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Copy.execute(Copy.java:549)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.artifactdeployer.service.LocalCopy.copyAndGetNumbers(LocalCopy.java:61)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.artifactdeployer.service.ArtifactDeployerCopy.invoke(ArtifactDeployerCopy.java:48)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.artifactdeployer.service.ArtifactDeployerCopy.invoke(ArtifactDeployerCopy.java:18)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:793)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:775)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.artifactdeployer.ArtifactDeployerBuilder.processDeployment(ArtifactDeployerBuilder.java:101)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.artifactdeployer.ArtifactDeployerBuilder.perform(ArtifactDeployerBuilder.java:46)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:34)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.build(Build.java:181)
at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.doRun(Build.java:136)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:524)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1493)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jna.TypeMapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:429)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:382)
```

Comment: were you able to solve it ?

Comment: I had to move from hudson to jenkins. After some research I found that Jenkins is the project that is more actively developed, so I moved to it. That solved the problem